# how to get unidentified network adaptor name with batch

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, batch-file

[image: Red arrow]

I already knew how to get all network adaptors names, but I can't tell the difference between normally using and not identified

By using 
netsh interface ip show interfaces 
or other commands ,you may get all adaptors names.

Answer (score 3):

The necessary information can be obtained using the [`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-networkadapter) class.
For example:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter @'
NetConnectionID = "Local Area Connection" AND
NetConnectionStatus=2 AND NetEnabled = True AND PhysicalAdapter = True
'@ | Format-List *
```

The [`Get-WmiObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-3.0#description) cmdlet can also be used, but starting in PowerShell 3.0,  it has been superseded by [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-3.0).
Starting with Windows 8, you can use the [`Get-NetAdapter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapter?view=winserver2012-ps) cmdlet.